# How to scale up a model in a training dataset to cover all aspects of training data

Tags: machine-learning

I was asked in an interview to solve a use case with the help of machine learning. I have to use a Machine Learning algorithm to identify fraud from transactions. My training dataset has lets say 100,200 transactions, out of which 100,000 are legal transactions and 200 are fraud.

I cannot use the dataset as a whole to make the model because it would be a biased dataset and the model would be a very bad one.

Lets say for example I take a sample of 200 good transactions which represent the dataset well(good transactions), and the 200 fraud ones and make the model using this as the training data.

The question I was asked was that how would I scale up the 200 good transactions to the whole data set of 100,000 good records so that my result can be mapped to all types of transactions. I have never solved this kind of a scenario so I did not know how to approach it.

Any kind of guidance as to how I can go about it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general question thrown in an interview. Information about the problem is succinct and vague (we don't know for example the number of features!). First thing you need to ask yourself is What do the interviewer wants me to respond? So, based on this context the answer has to be formulated in a similar general way. This means that we don't have to find 'the solution' but instead give arguments that show that we actually know how to **approach** the problem instead of **solving** it.

The problem we have presented with is that the minority class (fraud) is only a ~0.2% of the total. This is obviously a huge imbalance. A predictor that only predicted all cases as 'non fraud' would get a classification accuracy of 99.8%! Therefore, definitely something has to be done.

We will define our main task as a binary classification problem where we want to predict whether a transaction is labelled as positive (fraud) or negative (not fraud).

The first step would be considering what techniques we do have available to reduce imbalance. This can be done either by reducing the majority class (undersampling) or increasing the number of minority samples (oversampling). Both have drawbacks though. The first implies a severe loss of potential useful information from the dataset, while the second can present problems of overfitting. Some techniques to improve overfitting are SMOTE and ADASYN, which use strategies to improve variety in the generation of new synthetic samples.

Of course, cross-validation in this case becomes paramount. Additionally, in case we are finally doing oversampling, this has to be 'coordinated' with the cross-validation approach to ensure we are making the most of these two ideas. Check http://www.marcoaltini.com/blog/dealing-with-imbalanced-data-undersampling-oversampling-and-proper-cross-validation for more details.

Apart from these sampling ideas, when selecting our learner, many ML methods can be trained/optimised for specific metrics. In our case, we do not want to optimise accuracy definitely. Instead, we want to train the model to optimise either **ROC-AUC** or specifically looking for a **high recall** even at a loss of precission, as we want to predict all the positive 'frauds' or at least raise an alarm even though some will prove false alarms. Models can adapt internal parameters (thresholds) to find the optimal balance between these two metrics. Have a look at this nice blog for more info about metrics: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/7-important-model-evaluation-error-metrics/

Finally, is only a matter of evaluate the model empirically to check what options and parameters are the most suitable given the dataset. Following these ideas does not guarantee 100% that we are going to be able to tackle the problem at hand. But it ensures we are in a much better position to try to learn from data and being able to get rid of those evil fraudsters out there, while perhaps getting a nice job along the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this problem you want to classify transactions as good or fraud. However **your data is really imbalance**. In that you will probably be interested by [Anomaly detection](https://iwringer.wordpress.com/2015/11/17/anomaly-detection-concepts-and-techniques/). I will let you read all the article for more details but I will quote a few parts in my answer.

I think this will convince you that this is what you are looking for to solve this problem:

> **Is it not just Classification?**
>
> The answer is yes if the following three conditions are met.
>
> You have labeled training data Anomalous and normal classes are
>   balanced ( say at least 1:5) Data is not autocorrelated. ( That one
>   data point does not depend on earlier data points. This often breaks
>   in time series data). If all of above is true, we do not need an
>   anomaly detection techniques and we can use an algorithm like Random
>   Forests or Support Vector Machines (SVM).
>
> However, often it is very hard to find training data, and  even when
>   you can find them, most anomalies are 1:1000 to 1:10^6 events where
>   classes are not balanced.

**Now to answer your question:**

> Generally, the class imbalance is solved using an ensemble built by
>   resampling data many times.  The idea is to first create new datasets
>   by taking all anomalous data points and adding a subset of normal data
>   points (e.g. as 4 times as anomalous data points). Then a classifier
>   is built for each data set using SVM or Random Forest, and those
>   classifiers are combined using ensemble learning. This approach has
>   worked well and produced very good results.
>
> If the data points are autocorrelated with each other, then simple
>   classifiers would not work well. We handle those use cases using time
>   series classification techniques or Recurrent Neural networks.

I would also suggest **another approach of the problem**. In this article the author said:

> If you do not have training data, still it is possible to do anomaly
>   detection using unsupervised learning and semi-supervised learning.
>   However, after building the model, you will have no idea how well it
>   is doing as you have nothing to test it against. Hence, the results of
>   those methods need to be tested in the field before placing them in
>   the critical path.

However you do have a few fraud data to test if your unsupervised algorithm is doing well or not, and if it is doing a good enough job, it can be a first solution that will help gathering more data to train a supervised classifier later.

---

*Note that I am not an expert and this is just what I've come up with after mixing my knowledge and some articles I read recently on the subject.*

**For more question about machine learning** I suggest you to use [this stackexchange community](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Im looking for a method to scale up the result, not for alternate methods.

Comment: @sohil if you read the second text I quote in my answer it explains how to squale up your idea to exploit all the data you have: "Generally, the class imbalance is solved using an ensemble built by resampling data many times [...]"